# Merge [remote-desktop] and [terminal-services]

Tags: discussion, retag-request

Tags [remote-desktop](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/remote-desktop) and [terminal-services](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/terminal-services) refer to the same thing. I think that [terminal-services](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/terminal-services) should remain, since it is the official name of the functionality, also it covers more than just remoting into a Windows computer.

Possibly related tag: [fast-user-switching](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/fast-user-switching)

Comment: They are the same thing, but one covers more than the other?

Comment: @DanielBeck Yes. They are two names for the same, but with [tag:remote-desktop] it is not obvious that it also covers functionality like FUS.

Comment: I disagree with using [tag:terminal-services]: *Microsoft currently refers to their official RDP server software as Remote Desktop Services, formerly "Terminal Services". Their official client software is currently referred to as Remote Desktop Connection, formerly "Terminal Services Client".* and *This version was released to manufacturing in July 2009 and is included with Windows Server 2008 R2, as well as with Windows 7. With this release, the server name was also changed from Terminal Services to Remote Desktop Services.* It's also the more visible/common name, which will help searches.

Comment: At first blush I read [remote-desktop] as an RDP or remote support client. [terminal-services] is a server side component, and can even include mainframe terminals, which has nothing to do with a desktop.

Answer (score 6):

Don't merge anything.

Remote desktop is a more generic concept than Terminal Services.

Comment: The tag [tag:remote-desktop] has synonyms [tag:rdp] and [tag:mstsc], which suggests it is intended for Microsoft Terminal Services

Comment: No, because the synonyms map *to* the Remote Desktop tag, not the other way round. Which makes sense, since for example there are more than 70 questions for Linux and more than 70 for OS X which also use the Remote Desktop tag. Remote Desktop isn't specific to Windows (or Microsoft, for that matter). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_remote_desktop_software – so, if at all, merge Terminal Services into Remote Desktop.

Comment: except that [tag:rdp] and [tag:mstsc] are terms for Microsoft Terminal Services, not for generic remote desktop.

Answer (score 3):

Merge [terminal-services](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/terminal-services) into [remote-desktop](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/remote-desktop).

Answer (score -1):

Merge [remote-desktop](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/remote-desktop) into [terminal-services](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/terminal-services).